# php check the button is set and show some message

Tags: php

I have a markup like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right add-customer" name="add-new-customer">Add New Cusomer</button>
```

so when the add new customer will be clicked it should show some message. like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add-new-customer'])) {
    echo 'Set';
}
?>
```

but it is not doing isset for the button. So can somone tell me how to solve this using php. I have not used any kind of form. I want to simply check the button is set and show some message. Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Did you wrapped the `button` into a `form` tag?

Comment: nope..I have not used any form here...

Comment: @NewUser : you need to sumbit the button. Moreover, you need a form to accomplish such, or just use AJAX :). If you haven't wrapped the button into a form, then I don't think that a submit button will be enough.

Comment: Luckily @Sir_Winn3r got that, he is the only one until now who clearly understood the problem in the answers :D

Answer (score 4):

This is because if you click a button within a form it doesnt actually submit the form.

Try using

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="add-new-customer" />
```

EDIT:
Having just seen your comment, you must wrap the elements in a 
`<form>`

Answer (score 4):

Button elements aren't linked to anything in HTML. PHP won't detect if you click on a button.
You have to use a form or an AJAX query in order to populate the $_POST variable.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="add-new-customer" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

button type must be submit like `type="submit"` not `type="button"`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right add-customer" name="add-new-customer">Add New Cusomer</button>
```

also use `form` tag